# What is the object equality standard in PowerShell and how does ServiceController define the Equals method?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0

I tried these commands in PowerShell:

```
$a1 = (Get-Service)
$a2 = (Get-Service)
$a1[0] -eq $a2[0]
```

To my surprise, the result is false. Then I double checked their value and found they are the same service.

How could two objects that belongs to the same service not equal be to each other?

What is the object equality standard in PowerShell?

I found a part of the reason is because the method Equals in System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController Object returns false.

But how does the system compare? It is what I don't understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same object. They may contain the same *data* or *values*, but they are different *instances* of the `ServiceController` object.

Take, for example, the below:

```
$obj = new-object pscustomobject -Property @{123=456}
$obj2 = new-object pscustomobject -Property @{123=456}
```

Would you expect these to be the *same* object? Even though they contain the same data, they are two separate instances, so `$obj1 -eq $obj2` will always return `$false`

Equally, using the `equals()` method from .NETs [`System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), from which everything inherits:

```
> $obj.equals($obj2)
False
```

Comment: Different instances of string object can be equal. So being the same object does not mean being equal in powershell

Comment: If you were right, then every two objects that are not the same instances should not be equal

Comment: But a string is a primitive, so the `-eq` operator will always compare the *value*. I think you're not understanding the difference between comparing the *instance* of an object and the *value* an object holds. If you were right, then the example I gave would equal `True`, would it not?

Comment: To address your first comment, this is possible, but it's not what you mean. The **values** of different string objects can be equal, but it's unlikely in Powershell that the **instances** will be

Comment: How do you know I don't understand? In Python, there are two ways to tell this. == means to compare the value of instance while "is" means to compare whether two objects are the same . Your final answer is right but too late. It was post later than I found the real reason.

Comment: `I think you don't understand` is not *saying* you don't understand, it's my perception of the situation, not a definite. You're still to convince me otherwise however!

Comment: Sorry, I found that your answer still doesn't tell me the standard.

Comment: But you did give me a good tips. So I added a useful vote to your answer but haven't accepted it right now.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to know? What do you mean by **the standard**? The standard way of comparing object *instances* or object *values*?

Comment: So you mean the class of this object doesn't redefine the Equals but just inherits from System.Object? BTW, thanks to your posts, now I decide not to use powershell in this project. Ironpython won't have such problem.

Comment: Correct. Powershell is basically built on .NET. The class you're dealing with is a `ServiceController`, you can get that by `$a1[0].gettype()`. You can see from [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the `equals()` method inherits directly from `System.Object`

Answer (score 0):

I found a part of the reason. That is because the `Equals` method of System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController returns the false value.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer your own question - aren't you asking *why* it returns false? This doesn't address that

Comment: Yes I did answer my own question. Because why it returns false doesn't matter. You can define a class whose Equals method always returns false, then the object is not equal to it self.